# Prevent PHP from running until POST

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, post

So I'm really really really new to PHP and MySQL (just started today!).

I have a page that updates a MySQL database based on results from a post.

The way I have it now, the PHP code is on the page, and it works, but the problem is that it goes through on page load as well, that is, before the POST happens.

Any way to prevent this?

Here's my code:

```
        <?php
            //do stuff

            // see if any rows were returned
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
//do something
                  }
            }
            else {
//do something else
            }

            // free result set memory
            mysql_free_result($result);
            $first = 0;
        ?>
        <br />
        <br />

          <div id="addName">  
            <h3 class="caps">Want to add yourself?</h3>  

            <div class="box">  

            <br /> <br />
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="#">

            Email:
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </label>

              <label>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
              </label>

            </form>
            </div>  

          </div>  

        </div>
```

See, problem is that it will run //do something else before the form is filled out. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better Condition

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST) ){
  // now do with your post data
}
```

this will prevent empty data to be posted

Comment: You may wish to handle the checking of errors (missing data) in the conditional statement, with that, you cannot.

Comment: @Prisnor  why so?? `$_POST` is an array and i can check that array is empty or not

Comment: If `$_POST['submit']` is set, that necessarily implies `$_POST` is not empty.

Comment: i suppose it would be preferrable to reverse that order, but whats the big deal? the `empty` could short-circuit out the `isset` but an isset like that doesnt cause errors anyway

Comment: @Matthes if i click directly on submit button then `var_dump(isset($_POST['submit'])` returns `true`...( i have been faced such a problem)

Comment: @Jon, the order is not really the issue, and I didn't say it caused errors.  The `empty` is redundant either way.  If submit is set, POST is not empty.  If POST is not empty, you still need to know if submit is set.  @di, how does that address what I said?  If the submit field is the only thing thing set, POST will still not be empty.

Comment: @matthew -- right, but i dont see how it prevents 'the checking of errors (missing data) in teh conditional statement'.  its not better, but no worse either.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // do things when post has been made
  // e.g. insert the data into SQL
}
```

Take a read of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) page. The above code will check to make sure the submit button has been pressed.

Comment: Ahh, of course! Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the HTML form on a different page you can put this at the top of your code on the PHP page.  It will redirect the user to the HTML form file before any code is executed.

```
if (!$_POST['submit']) {
   header("Location: ./form.html");
   die();
}
```

However if you prefer to keep the form on the same page (which it looks like you are) you can use the suggestions above.